# Detect static super method in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have one base class and a subclass. I want my class types to have a static method that identifies it by a string. (So I can do a look up in an object for handlers of a type. I can stick the class in it directly, but converts the entire source of the class to a string and uses that as the key, which seems suboptimal.)

I need to:

- detect the presence of a super class

  - call `super.id()` then append my own `id()`
- if no super just send my own `id()`

Here is how I'd imagine the code to be written, but `super.id` is undefined, so the `if` always fails. Checking for `if (super) {}` also fails as a syntax error and `super.id()` fails as it's "not a function".

```
class Y {
  static id() {
    if (super.id) {
      return `${super.id()}-${this.name}`;
    }
    else {
      return this.name;
    }
  }
}

class YY extends Y {}

// Outputs "Y YY", but I want "Y Y-YY"
console.log(Y.id(), YY.id())
```

I could define a `static id() {}` method in `YY`, but then I'd have to manually do it in all my subclasses which is error prone. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: And using `Map` is not an option?

Comment: It's an option, but I'd rather use an Object and it was sort of academic interest too.

Comment: The point is that the string cannot unmistakably identify the class, but the class itself could. So a Map or WeakMap would be the technical better way so solve such a problem.

Comment: "*static method that identifies it by a string*" - why not simply use `klass.name`?

Comment: @Bergi I want to include the inheritance chain in the ID (called descriptor in my code, probably poor form to shorten it for StackO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `super`:

```js
class Y {
  static id() {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(this).id) {
      return `${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).id()}-${this.name}`;
    }
    else {
      return this.name;
    }
  }
}

class YY extends Y {}

console.log(Y.id(), YY.id())
```

With `super` it does not work, since that always refers to the prototype of the `Y` class. But `this` matches exactly the object you need the prototype of, so with `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).id` you get a nice bubbling-up through the prototype chain.

Comment: Make sure to always validate prototype and id being function: `static id() {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    if (proto && typeof proto.id === 'function') {
      return proto.id() + '-' + this.name;
    }
    return this.name;
  }`

Comment: "*`super` always refers to the prototype of the Y instance.*" - there is no instance in a static method. It refers to the prototype of the class itself, i.e. the superclass (`Y` for `YY` and `Function.prototype` for `Y`).